# How to exclude blank attributes from Django Rest?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have, in models.py :

```
class Bedrooms_types(models.Model):
    bedrooms_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.bedrooms_type

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('bedrooms_type',)

class Buildings(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    category=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    bedrooms_types = models.ManyToManyField(Bedrooms_types)
    bedrooms = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    construction_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

and in serializers.py :

```
class BuildingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

bedrooms_types = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)
```

when I load url `/building/` I get:

```
[{"bedrooms_types": ["grande-suite", "junior-suite"], "id": 1, "name": "Hilton", "category": "hotel", "type": "4-star", "bedrooms": "100", "owner": "", "construction_date": null}]
```

Fields bedrooms, construction_date and owner can be empty.  How to change serializer.py to not show these fields when they are empty?

For this example, I want to get:

```
[{"bedrooms_types": ["grande-suite", "junior-suite"], "id": 1, "name": "Hilton", "category": "hotel", "type": "4-star", "bedrooms": "100", "}]
```

Comment: You could override the serializer's `get_fields` method to exclude the fields, that are empty in the instance. `get_fields` returns a sorted dict of name:field. The instance is `self.object`.

Comment: please more details how to do it, example ?

Answer (score 3):

You can override `to_representation` to clean up the serialized model

```
class ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        repr_dict = super(ModelSerializer, self).to_representation(value)
        return OrderedDict((k, v) for k, v in repr_dict.items() 
                           if v not in [None, [], '', {}])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer with more details:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Buildings

EMPTY_VALUES = ('', None, [], ())

class BuildingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    bedrooms_types = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Buildings

    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super(BuildingSerializer, self).get_fields()
        return OrderedDict(
            ((name, field) for name, field in fields.iteritems()
                if getattr(self.object, name) not in EMPTY_VALUES)
        )
```

Comment: For recent versions of Django (1.8+, at least), that will need to be `getattr(self.instance.model, name, None)` as `object` no longer exists.  Also note that this will exclude 'synthetic' fields such as those using `SerializerMethodField`, no matter their value.